# How can a postgres 9.4 server know if a client is listening on a notify channel?

Tags: postgresql, notifications

I have a situation where I want to send out notification to users if they have been added to a particular table in my postgreSQL DB.

I am using pg_notify to send out a json payload to a NODE.js server that has implemented a pg client to listen on the notification channel. This works well.

What I can't decide is how best to inform the postgres server that someone is listening and the notify was received and is being processed. I would ideally like to use the same channel for the client to notify the server. However, as I understand it, the postgres server will only act as a hub for the channel, simply receiving the notification from the client and pushing it back to all other subscribed listeners.

Is this actually the case? Can I build a function on the postgres server that is triggered by incoming notifications on the channel?

The only other solution that occurs to me is to have a column in the table to record that a notification has been received an get the Node.js server to update the table on receipt of the notification, but this requires an additional connection that I would like to avoid.

Any thoughts or experience with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on how important it is to not miss a notification.

No, Postgres doesn't have functionality to listen for notifications from clients, but if you are connected to the Postgres server you could just do what you need done directly.

Postgres is not a message queue. It gives you LISTEN/NOTIFY that you can build more complex things with, but unless you really know what you are doing it isn't something I would advise.

If you need guaranteed delivery of messages, routing of messages, you are most likely better off using a real message queue like RabbitMQ for that part.

You could for example have a simple application listen on notifications from Postgres and put them on a message queue, which keeps the message until someone has read and acknowledged it.

If that application fails you will miss messages so if you need better guarantees you could have a trigger in Postgresql that puts the messages in a table as a backup.

Comment: Thanks, Björn. That is actually exactly how I ended up building it, using Rabbit. I even store the message in the database in case I need to resend them. I am then going to use pgAgent to check the message table at regular intervals for any messages that haven't been acknowledge (deleted) from that temp storage after a set amount of time. 

So I am pleased to see this solutions occurred to you too, it means I am not doing anything others wouldn't do.